# Double free corruption, what is wrong in my function free_list?

Tags: c, valgrind

I am implementing a linked list in C. After reading the comments I have updated and provided more code, which calls free(). If I run the code below I get the following error "double free or corruption (fasttop):" I strongly believe that this comes free_list, which probably is wrong. If I run

valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all

I'll get the following error "total heap usage: 4 allocs, 7 frees, 64 bytes allocated"

```
list_t* xmalloc(size_t size){
  list_t * t = malloc(size);

  if(t == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
  }
  return t;
}


/* a function new_list to create a new and empty list.*/
list_t* new_list(void){
  list_t* stack;
  stack =  xmalloc(sizeof(list_t));
  stack->value = NULL;
  stack->succ = NULL;
  return stack;
}

/* a function free_list to deallocate the list.*/
void free_list(list_t* head){
  list_t* temp;
  temp = head;
  while(head->succ != NULL){
    temp = head->succ;
    head->succ = head->succ->succ;
    free(temp);
  }
  free(head);
}

void insert_first(list_t* list, int* a){

  list_t* t;
  t = new_list();
  t->value = a;
  t->succ = list->succ;
  list->succ = t;
  free(t);
}

int top(list_t* stack){
  if(stack->succ == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Empty\n");

  }
  return *stack->succ->value;
}

int main(void){
  int a[3] = {1,2,3};
  int i;
  list_t* head1;
  head1 = new_list();
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    insert_first(head1, &a[i]);
  }
  printf("Top1: %d\n", top(head1));
}
 free_list(head1);
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell where the problem is since you have posted only part of your program. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does Valgrind tell you that something is definitely unreachable? Or just still reachable?  Did you run valgrind with `--leak-check=full`?

Comment: My understanding is that `valgrind` will tell you where the memory was allocated and not where the any pointer to that memory was lost. That bit you need to figure out with the debugger

Comment: @Kaz yes I ran it with --leak-check=full and --show-leak-kinds=all

Comment: Alright, so you haven't `free()`ed all your list nodes... do you have code that removes items from the list, or that frees the list when you're done with it?

Comment: @Olba12 You code doesn't show any of the parts of the program which create a list, and call `insert_first` to add to the list, and then clean up the list. The one and only `free` operation shown is actually a red herring that doesn't do anything.

Comment: I have made an edit @Kaz. I believe the problem is in the free_list function

Comment: If you want absolutely no leaks reported, you have to do `fclose(stdin); fclose(stdout); fclose(stderr);` These objects are still allocated at termination.  Usually we don't care about "still reachable" bytes, only "definitely lost".   If your program doesn't show runaway memory growth and doesn't show "definitely lost" bytes when run to termination under valgrind, don't worry about it.

Comment: The `free_list` function is oddly coded, but the logic is correct. Basically `head->succ` is a stack and you pop that stack in a loop, freeing the top node; then you free the stack itself.  This could be done more simply, but it doesn't seem to be leaking. (It can be done more simply because `head` is no different from the rest of the nodes in the stack; there is no need to give it special treatment).

Comment: Side issue: why use `sizeof(list_t)` in `stack =  xmalloc(sizeof(list_t));`?  How about `stack =  xmalloc(sizeof *stack);`?  No need to update the code should the type of `stack` change.

Answer (score 2):

You have a useless `temp` variable in this function. That is suspicious. However, this function doesn't leak, by itself.

```
void insert_first(list_t* list, int* a){
  list_t* t;
  t = new_list();
```

After this `new_list`, `t->succ` is null

```
  t->value = a;
```

`t->succ` is still null.

```
  list_t* temp;
  temp = t->succ;
```

Since `t->succ` is null, so is `temp`.

```
  t->succ = list->succ;
  list->succ = t;
  free(temp);
```

So `free(temp)` is just `free(NULL)`; it does nothing.

```
}
```

Comment: Since it does nothing, why is it reported as a memory leak?

Comment: Although this is correct, I don't see how it addresses the question at all...

Comment: Then it should be  t = new_list(); that does a leakage and hence should be free:ed?

Comment: @Olba12 The allocated node referenced by `t` is spliced into `list`.  After this function executes, `list->succ` points to `t` and `t->succ` points to the original successor of `list` which was `list->succ`.  If `list` isn't leaked, then `t` isn't leaked.

Comment: Oh this was really good, and It solved all my problems! Sorry for being so confusing. Now I understand it. @Kaz